# Checking for the like button when switching between screens

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I can't figure out the reason for this bug. There is a post feed that has a ListView and contains the PostCell class; this class also has activity buttons (likes, comments, etc.) as a separate class. Also in this postCell there is navigation to the detailed page of the post where there are also activity buttons as a separate class. So, when I go back to the feed from the detailed page, my likes do not immediately update. Why? I don't pass any parameters when exiting.

```
class FeedView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FeedViewState createState() => _FeedViewState();
}

class _FeedViewState extends State<FeedView> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFF1D1332),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF1D1332),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: RefreshIndicator(
                  onRefresh: _refreshData,
                  color: mainPurple,
                  child: Center(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: wishes.length + 1,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        if (index == wishes.length) {
                          return isLoading
                              ? Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: (screenHeight - 350.0) / 2,
                              ),
                              CircularProgressIndicator(color: mainPurple),
                              SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                            ],
                          )
                              : Container();
                        } else {
                          return Padding(
                            key: ValueKey<String>(wishes[index].id),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 8.0,
                              horizontal: 16.0,
                            ),
                            child: WishCell(wish: wishes[index]),
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WishCell extends StatefulWidget {
  final Wish wish; 
  final Key? key; 

  WishCell({required this.wish, this.key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WishCellState createState() => _WishCellState();
}


class _WishCellState extends State<WishCell> {
  String id = ''; 


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WishDetailView(wish: widget.wish)),
        );
      },
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFF0F0820),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          boxShadow: [
            if (isPremium)
              BoxShadow(
                color: mainPurple.withOpacity(0.5),
                spreadRadius: 2,
                blurRadius: 5,
                offset: Offset(0, 3),
              ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl:
                    'image',
                    placeholder: (context, url) => CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/default_image.png'),
                      radius: 28,
                    ),
                    imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: imageProvider,
                      radius: 28,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              widget.wish.fullname,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 5),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              widget.wish.username,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 10),
                            Text(
                              formatTimestamp(widget.wish.timestamp),
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
                            ),
                            
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16.0),
              Text(
                widget.wish.caption,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
                maxLines: 2, 
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, 
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16.0),
              WishActionsView(wish: widget.wish), 
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WishDetailView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Wish wish;

  WishDetailView({required this.wish});

  @override
  _WishDetailViewState createState() => _WishDetailViewState();
}

class _WishDetailViewState extends State<WishDetailView> {
  String id = '';


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Perform> performs = widget.wish.performs;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF1D1332),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(210, 39, 222, 1),
                          ),
                          tooltip: 'Назад',
                        ),
                        Spacer(),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 56,
                          height: 56,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: isPremium ? mainPurple : Colors.transparent,
                              width: 2.0,

                            ),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: isPremium ? mainPurple.withOpacity(0.5) : Colors.transparent,
                                spreadRadius: 2,
                                blurRadius: 8,
                                offset: Offset(0, 4),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: CachedNetworkImage(
                            imageUrl: 'image',
                            placeholder: (context, url) => CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/default_image.png'),
                            ),
                            imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundImage: imageProvider,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              widget.wish.fullname,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  widget.wish.username,
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Spacer(),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    Text(
                      widget.wish.caption,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                    Text(
                      '${widget.wish.timestamp.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}.${widget.wish.timestamp.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}.${widget.wish.timestamp.year}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16),
                    WishActionsView(wish: widget.wish),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          if (isLoadingDelete)
            Container(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Color(0xFFD227DE)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WishActionsView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Wish wish;

  WishActionsView({required this.wish});

  @override
  _WishActionsViewState createState() => _WishActionsViewState();
}

class _WishActionsViewState extends State<WishActionsView>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool liked = false;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkIfLiked().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        liked = value;
      });
    });
  }


  Future<http.Response> addLikeToWish(String wishId, String caption,
      String username, String likedUsername, String selectedImagePath,
      String fullname, int likes) async {
    final token = await _getToken();

    final String apiUrl = 'localhost/like-wish';

    final Map<String, dynamic> requestBody = {
      'wishId': wishId,
      'caption': caption,
      'username': username,
      'likedUsername': likedUsername,
      'selectedImagePath': selectedImagePath,
      'fullname': fullname,
      'likes': likes,
    };

    final headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    };

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(apiUrl),
      headers: headers,
      body: jsonEncode(requestBody),
    );

    return response;
  }

  Future<http.Response> removeLikeFromWish(String wishId, String caption,
      String username, likedUsername) async {
    final token = await _getToken();

    final String apiUrl = 'http://localhost/unlike-wish';

    final Map<String, dynamic> requestBody = {
      'wishId': wishId,
      'caption': caption,
      'username': username,
      'likedUsername': likedUsername,
    };

    final headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    };

    final response = await http.delete(
      Uri.parse(apiUrl),
      headers: headers,
      body: jsonEncode(requestBody),
    );

    return response;
  }

  Future<bool> checkIfLiked() async {
    final token = await _getToken();
    final String apiUrl = 'http://localhost/check-like';

    final Map<String, dynamic> requestBody = {
      'wishId': widget.wish.id,
    };

    final headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    };

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(apiUrl),
      headers: headers,
      body: jsonEncode(requestBody),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return data['liked'];
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isCommentEmpty = textEditingController.text.isEmpty;
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    liked ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                    color: liked ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (!isProcessing) {
                      setState(() {
                        isProcessing = true;
                      });

                      if (liked) {
                        final response = await removeLikeFromWish(
                            widget.wish.id,
                            widget.wish.caption,
                            widget.wish.username,
                            widget.wish.uid);
                        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                          print("Лайк удален");
                          setState(() {
                            widget.wish.likes--;
                            liked = false;
                          });
                        } else {
                          print('Ошибка при удалении лайка');
                        }
                      } else {
                        final response = await addLikeToWish(
                            widget.wish.id,
                            widget.wish.caption,
                            widget.wish.username,
                            widget.wish.uid,
                            widget.wish.selectedImagePath,
                            widget.wish.fullname,
                            widget.wish.likes);
                        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                          print("Лайк добавлен");
                          setState(() {
                            widget.wish.likes++;
                            liked = true;
                          });
                        } else {
                          print('Ошибка при добавлении лайка');
                        }
                      }

                      setState(() {
                        isProcessing = false;
                      });
                    }
                  },
                ),
                Text(
                  widget.wish.likes.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to pass like values, tried to call the checkifLiked function, but the only thing I achieved was updating the number when exiting wishDetailView. But the like button still changes only if I re-login

Comment: I didn't fully understood you code, i think you should be have liked values in your wish class, then you should take it from there, on `initState` take the like count from there, and if you don't i think you should that's how things should work. Don't need to fetch every time when user come to that screen.